# Start tshark with xml filter

Tags: xml, wireshark, tshark

The command line alternative to WireShark is tshark. I want to filter out the XML tpye of messages. I would like to ask for help in this regard.

```
@SET ws=C:\Program Files\Wireshark
@SET capture=D:\TSHARK_CAPTURE
chdir %ws%
del %capture%\*.pcapng
tshark -i 1 <some filter> -w %capture%\capture.pcapng
```

How can I solve this problem with tshark? Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[Capture filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters)
You cannot directly filter [XML](https://wiki.wireshark.org/XML) protocols while capturing.
If you know the TCP port used, you can filter on that one.
Capture only the XML traffic over HTTP that uses HTTP's default port (80): 
tcp port 80